# systemd daemon that should never terminate deactivates "successfully"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I run a daemon process under `systemd` (that sits around and watches a bunch of RSS feeds and sends notifications about them). It's a (Scala) JVM process that's essentially an infinite loop.

The process starts up beautifully, but eventually, mysteriously, logs itself `Deactivated successfully`. In the `systemctl status` output, it claims to have exited successfully, with exit code 0.

But there should be no successful exit. It's an infinite loop! I've [added logging to the end of the main function](https://github.com/swaldman/feedletter/blob/31c3591571339d96ce7b386dbbed58a609ea88c6/src/com/mchange/feedletter/AbstractMain.scala#L125-L139), logging `SEVERE` notions if somehow the line that's supposed to be an infinite loop terminates, or if any `Throwable` were to occur.

Nothing is logged. A termination on signal would have showed up in the journals, and would not have been a successful exit. I have `Restart=on-failure`. (I could work around the issue, I think, with `Restart=always`, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.)

I don't understand how the process exits successfully from `systemd`'s perspective but can never exit successfully from mine.

An unusual aspect of my configuration is that I run the daemon under `systemd` as `Type=forking` rather than `Type=simple`. I let its build tool (the wonderful [`mill`](https://mill-build.com/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html)) rebuild then fork it, so I can edit some template and config files that, via code-generation, get compiled into the daemon. All of this seems to be working: `mill` successfully rebuilds and launches the process on every `systemct start` or `restart`, the daemon process successfully forks, and runs for some time — looking at the lastest event, almost exactly 50 minutes — before any mysterious deactivation. The subprocess, rather than the forking parent, emits the `PID` file, so `systemd` complains

```
feedletter.service: Can't open PID file /home/feedletter/feedletter-local/feedletter.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

but soon finds the file, I presume, because it does not time out.

Here's the latest `systemctl status` output:

```
# systemctl status feedletter 
○ feedletter.service - Feedletter RSS-To-Mail-Etc Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/feedletter.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-01-26 09:07:20 UTC; 10h ago
   Duration: 49min 57.712s
   Main PID: 10994 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 55.934s

Jan 26 08:51:38 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:51:38 [INFO] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Subscription with ID 2 has been marked confirmed.
Jan 26 08:51:45 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:51:45 [INFO] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Subscription with ID 3 has been marked confirmed.
Jan 26 08:59:23 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:23 [FINE] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Deleting any as-yet-unassigned items that have been deleted from feed with ID 1
Jan 26 08:59:23 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:23 [INFO] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Updated/assigned all items from feed with ID 1, feed URL 'https://lawyersgunsdev.wpengine.com/feed'
Jan 26 08:59:33 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:33 [FINE] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Updated last-checked-time on a stable already-assigned, not yet cleared, item, feed ID 2, guid 'tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-3456975.post-7737119998523372540'.
Jan 26 08:59:33 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:33 [FINE] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Updated last-checked-time on a stable already-assigned, not yet cleared, item, feed ID 2, guid 'tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-3456975.post-7431934517490670965'.
Jan 26 08:59:33 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:33 [FINE] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Deleting any as-yet-unassigned items that have been deleted from feed with ID 2
Jan 26 08:59:33 feedletter-play feedletter[10994]: 2024-01-26@08:59:33 [INFO] [com.mchange.feedletter.db.PgDatabase] Updated/assigned all items from feed with ID 2, feed URL 'https://www.eschatonblog.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss'
Jan 26 09:07:20 feedletter-play systemd[1]: feedletter.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 26 09:07:20 feedletter-play systemd[1]: feedletter.service: Consumed 55.934s CPU time.
```

Here's the unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Feedletter RSS-To-Mail-Etc Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/feedletter/feedletter-local/feedletter.pid
User=feedletter
Group=feedletter
WorkingDirectory=/home/feedletter/feedletter-local

ExecStart=/home/feedletter/feedletter-local/feedletter daemon --fork

TimeoutStopSec=90
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
StandardError=journal
StandardOutput=journal
StandardInput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The OS is Ubuntu 23.10.

Any help or insight would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a wrinkle in how I was forking the daemons with `mill`.

That build tool's `runBackground` tasks do easily fork processes for you, but they [wrap them in a kind of reaper](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/blob/e171ad4c57c34a0bff2325327f8afc98d009f63d/scalalib/backgroundwrapper/src/mill/scalalib/backgroundwrapper/BackgroundWrapper.java) that watches for changes in the source for the process, and automatically terminates the forked process, "successfully", with exit code 0, when that occurs.

My infinite loop was always infinite-looping. It's just that there was another thread watching some files and shutting down the process that contained the loop on unexpectedly significant events.

To overcome this, I [wrote an extension to `mill`](https://github.com/swaldman/mill-daemon) that defines `runDaemon` tasks, which reproduce the nice, forking `runBackground` tasks without running this sneaky suicide thread. The extension can also emit a PID file before terminating, adhering fully to the forking protocol `systemd` expects.

With this in place, my rebuild-on-launch daemons run predictably and reliably.